# Image right, text left works, but image left, text right doesn't (for website)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am creating a website and trying to get the best css setup (responsive/works on all browsers) for creating a section where an image is either right or left of a block of text. I heard that flex was the best way to go, so I tried mimicking other websites that use a flex setup. So far I have a chunk of code that works for when the image is to the right, and the text is to the left....but it doesn't work for when image is to the left, and the text is to the right.

Here's my code: https://codepen.io/7harrypotterrr/pen/MZEdVY

```
.containerabcolumn {margin: 0 auto !important;}
```

As you can see, when I reverse the orders of div a and b, the results are bad. On my actual site, there's actually no overlap, but theres an issue with how the image overflows. When the window size is shrunk down for the first section of code, things works as intended...the image to the right goes beyond its div container and cuts off more and more as the window size is shrunk (that's good)....however for the second section of code where the image is to the left and text right, the image ends up overlapping the text...instead of going beyond its container to the left (the way I want it to).

Any ideas how to fix?

Thanks in advance for any help I get, and as you can tell from the way I tried to describe my issue, I am a complete noob at coding.

Also, if anyone have thoughts as to whether this set of code is responsive/works on all browsers/generally a smart approach, that would be great too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask for the right approach so I will give two answers. Answer 1 answers your request. Answer 2 is a more elegant and professional solution that - with the same css - is able to display two views, optimized depending on the target screen

**Solution 1: respecting your intention also on mobile**

in order to have both the problems solved

1. this fix the text over the image, as per the other answer:

   .b img {
   width: 100%;
   }
2. removing `flex: 0 0 auto;` makes fixes the text cut on mobile:

   .a {
   -webkit-flex-basis: 41.667%;
   -ms-flex-preferred-size: 41.667%;
   flex-basis: 41.667%;
   max-width: 50%;
   margin: auto;
   }

This is a simulation on a Pixel2 XL after the two css modifications

[image: Pixel2XL_display]

**Solution 2: best UX**

The preceding solution mimics the dynamics of a desktop screen. But on a mobile you want to see better the text and the image. This doesn't happen with the preceding solution. So my suggestion is to go with this css. You will preserve the same layout you want on desktop screens BUT you will reorganize the things much better when you open the page on mobile

```
<style>
.containerabc {
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}    

.containerabcolumn {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    max-width: 1080px;
    float: none !important;
    position: static !important;
}

.containerabc .et_pb_text {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -0.5rem;
    margin-left: -0.5rem;
}

.a {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 41.667%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 41.667%;
    flex-basis: 41.667%;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}
   
.b {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 58.333%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 58.333%;
    flex-basis: 58.333%;
    max-width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-basis: auto;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
}

.b img {
    width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) 
{   
    .containerabc .et_pb_text 
    {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .a 
    {
        margin: unset;
        max-width: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    
    .b
    {
        max-width: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
    }
}
</style>
```

Desktop behavior

[image: desktop_view]

Mobile behavior

[image: mobile_view]

---

Update after OP clarification

```
.containerabc {
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}    

.containerabcolumn {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    max-width: 1080px;
    float: none !important;
    position: static !important;
}

.containerabc .et_pb_text {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -0.5rem;
    margin-left: -0.5rem;
}

.a {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 41.667%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 41.667%;
    flex-basis: 41.667%;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
    background: white;
}

.b {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 58.333%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 58.333%;
    flex-basis: 58.333%;
    max-width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-basis: auto;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
}

.b img {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 700px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) 
{   
    .containerabc .et_pb_text 
    {
        display: block;
    }

    .a 
    {
        margin: unset;
        max-width: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
        position: unset;
    }

    .b
    {
        max-width: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    
    .b img 
    {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: unset;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. The issue with that code I am having is that it no longer allows my image to overflow (maybe overflow isnt the right word here so let me explain further)

This is what I want in terms of how the image remains the same size but is cut off (everything else is messed up with words cut...especially the section with image left, wall of text right): https://imgur.com/a/6smb3aE
With the current solutions (width: 100% and no more flex, 0 0 auto) the image shrinks: https://imgur.com/a/1eSxPAG which is not my intention because the picture is meant to be very big on my website

Comment: ciao! unfortunately it is not clear to me what you really want. If I understood correctly for the first part [text on the left and image on the right] you want the image to maintain the original size without any problem if it gets cut on its right side, as it happened with the original code [please correct me if I'm wrong]. For the second part [image on the left and text on the right] I have no idea of what you are trying to get, can you please clarify?

Comment: Hiya, thanks for the reply! For both parts, I want the image to maintain the original size and cut out if necessary. As shown in  imgur.com/a/6smb3aE, the first part [text on the left and image on the right] is close to being done right....however as you can see in the second part [image on the left and text on the right], it's a complete mess.

Comment: By adding the width: 100%, and then later removing the flex...it fixes the text over image and allows the words to not cut out (like you said) but it also forces the image within its container...so now when the window size decreases, so does the image...instead for my design, I prefer it that when the window size decreases, the image size stays the same

Here's an example of what I mean (first image with the computer/phone screens): https://hire.google.com/product-overview/

The image cuts a bit/decreases in size only a little/leaves its container

Comment: ciao! just edited the code, I hope this is what you need. Have a good day

Comment: Thanks for the help. For the second section, is there a way to get the image to cut left instead of cut right? Or is that impossible with this current setup?

Comment: Hello! it is possible with some minimal adjustements to this solution. Try on your own first and then please open a new question if you will need support, this one has exploded already. A suggestion for the future: first have the vision of what you want to achieve and then ask, don't do it incrementally [you added a new spec at your 4th comment] because in general on this website it will not pay out. Have a good day and a beautiful 2019 mate!

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to define 'width: 100%;' to your image inside div. Something like:

```
.b img {
    max-width: 700px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This solution works correctly only on desktop. The OP is interested also in responsiveness and on mobile the text is cut. Also, as I say in part 2 of my answer keeping the OP approach is most probably not the optimized solution for these devices

Comment: @Antonino IMHO there is no need to use flexbox in mobile and event keep image and text in the same row - text under image is the best way to show detailed image and text in mobile devices.

Comment: Totally agree. I coded a few responsive pages and so far I never used flexbox. If you see my Solution2 when it comes to `@media only screen` there is nothing with flexbox. And the final layout for mobile is exactly "text under image", we seem to agree on this. Thanks for your reply and have a good day!

Comment: @Antonino yeah, that's a good solution :) Have a nice day too!